# How to generale partial/incremental updates used by “adb install-multiple”?

Tags: android, adb

adb has a "partial application install":

adb install-multiple [-lrtsdp] 
                               - push this package file to the device and install it
                                 (-l: forward lock application)
                                 (-r: replace existing application)
                                 (-t: allow test packages)
                                 (-s: install application on sdcard)
                                 (-d: allow version code downgrade)
                                 (-p: partial application install)
More specifically I want to update an apk by an incremental update.

How can I create the partial update file? I assume some utility is required which creates a binary diff between the new and previous version of APK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *partial application install* flag controls `PackageInstaller`'s [`SessionParams.MODE_INHERIT_EXISTING`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.SessionParams.html#MODE_INHERIT_EXISTING) mode. And the only officially documented use for it at the moment is to support installation of [APK splits](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html).

Comment: thanks....umm, so I am not able to create diffs / incremental updates between different versions of an app (a binary diff between appv1.apk and appv2.apk)?

Comment: at the most you may be able to handcraft a *delta* APK containing only files (whole files, not deltas) which were actually changed in between the 2 versions of your app. but even that is not the intended use of the feature - so no tools exist to help you to do that.

Comment: Just to be sure I was clear: What I want to do is to create a binary diff on the PC (using some command line tools) and then deploy the diff to simulator/device using Android tools (adb, shell, etc). Is this possible based on your knowledge?

Comment: you can make a binary diff and then `adb push` it to your device and then apply the patch with `adb shell applypatch` command. but that would be a completely different matter which would not be related in any way to your original question and `adb install-multiple` command

Comment: thanks! I edited my question. Sorry for being misleading. I thought `install-multiple` is what I need. thanks again. can you help me with how to run `call adb shell applypatch` exactly?